# Log Querying - identify errors cause by recent release

Tags: datadog

I would like to query for errors that occured recently (in the last 15 or 30 minutes) but were not encounter for several days (1 or 2 days) before that. The idea is to capture any errors that are related to a recent production release.

I can't quite figure our how to construct the query, so I would appreciate any help with it.
Also I would like to discover the patterns (Group into Patterns).

I constructed different queries but they did not produce the result I wanted. I am new to datadog, so I am not sure how to construct the query.